# IMPORTFROMWEB - XPATH - #ALL_SELECTORS_RETURN_NULL

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm using an excel google sheet with Function "import from web" and Xpath.

I am trying to extract the new events from this page below through Xpath, but the result is #ALL_SELECTORS_RETURN_NULL

Web Page: https://t.17track.net/en#nums=420379249374869903506792460931

Xpath:/html/body/main/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/p/span

Code in the Google sheet: =IMPORTFROMWEB([https://t.17track.net/en#nums=420379249374869903506792460931;/html/body/main/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/p/span](https://t.17track.net/en#nums=420379249374869903506792460931;/html/body/main/div/article/div%5B2%5D/div%5B1%5D/div/div/div%5B2%5D/div%5B1%5D/div%5B3%5D/p/span))

I can't figure out the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

google sheets is not able to import JavaScript content:

[image]

Comment: I turned it at the beginning but still no results :(

Comment: @JennySwift after you disable/block JavaScript on the website you can import in your google spreadsheet only the stuff you see with disabled JS. in your case its not much - logo and the title. the rest cannot be imported because google sheets does not support scrapping of JS elements